# UWP backup on users OneDrive

Tags: uwp, onedrive

I want to implement OneDrive backup for UWP store application - without asking user to enter Login/Password (user already loggedin MS account). Can you point to actual(modern) tutorial how to read and write files to "onedrive.appfolder" only.

I tried multiples examples about accessing OneDrive, all of them outdated and not working:
LiveSDK
OneDriveSDK(V1,V2)
Graph - From Azure Registration portal - two sample applications settled up for registered app - not working with windows auth.
Community.Toolkit.OneDriveService (in latest builds service removed with comment -> removing old service and outdated graph implementation). I did not found modern alternative.

I got two main problems:
Authorization, most examples made for corporate SharePoint access, all examples failed to use windows auth (without login promt) with error: Can not get user information: check app have right compatibility… It is not true - I can get loggedin user info by System.User , also on first run UWP asking to get Read Account permit. I believe I have done this part using WebAccountProvider with single OneDrive app folder permition question (Scope "onedrive.appfolder") and returned Token. Interesting, but I don't need to create Azure/ App registration to get access to OneDrive App - Store association is enough. But Token doesn't wont to work with Graph or OneDriveSDK V2.
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebAccountManagement

Second problem - using OneDrive to read and write folders/files - there is no clear documentation or examples.

Thanks,
Maksim

Answer (score 1):

First, you must auth you app to use `OneDrive` permission, which means your app will popup a login window, user input email and password, then your app can use `OneDrive` read & write permission. Then you can storage the token, and next time you can use this token to login without asking user again.

Second, WCT teams released an app named  `Windows Community Toolkit Sample App`, you can download from this [url](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-community-toolkit-sample-app/9nblggh4tlcq?irgwc=1&OCID=AID2000142_aff_7806_1246483&tduid=%28ir__mspcobhjr0kftn6rxmlij6lydu2xi01nrzni2mty00%29%287806%29%281246483%29%28%28ef8948e453d8b46aebdc80f7bf5c41d9%29%2881561%29%28686431%29%28at106140_a107739_m12_p12460_cHK%29%28%29%29%28ef8948e453d8b46aebdc80f7bf5c41d9%29&irclickid=_mspcobhjr0kftn6rxmlij6lydu2xi01nrzni2mty00&activetab=pivot:overviewtab).

Then in `Services` tab, their is `OneDrive Service`, refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/services/onedrive#syntax).

Comment: The first thing I am trying to avoid is a login window for OneDrive. I really hate to enter credentials multiple times for the same service I am already loggedin for simple App backup. Maximum I can ask user to confirm (yes/no) what OneDrive could be used to store application data. There is any way to avoid login window for windows store app backup?

Comment: Second, I failed to use Community toolkit from example [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/services/onedrive#syntax). I have Xamarin forms with UWP application, using Nuget I have installed Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Services and Microsoft.Toolkit.Services v6.1.0 and OneDrive class is missing from namespace Microsoft.Toolkit.Services.OneDrive.

Comment: Maybe onedrive service changed again. You can search more doc on google.

Answer (score 0):

I found the next solution to get simple access to OneDrive Api to save app backup.

To get authentication token I have used WebAccountProvider from [WebAccountManagment sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebAccountManagement).

To communicate with OneDrive Api I have used [Annotate Audio App Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ie/samples/microsoft/windows-appsample-annotated-audio/annotated-audio-app-sample/), also includes authentication and working with https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/ Api.

Api Documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/special-folders-appfolder?view=odsp-graph-online